# Populate Quote Name before Save with Opportunity Name - Flow Help

Tags: visual-workflow

Our guys used to be able to copy the text of the Opportunity and paste it as the Quote Name but since 23 release this is not possible (You can still do it in Sandbox though) the Opportunity name is a lookup with  an X instead of the name text.

[image: Prod]
[image: Sand]

I’ve created a flow that updates the Quote Name with the Opportunity Name on creation using a Record Triggered Flow that adds the quote name after I save it.  I am wanting to populate the Quote Name when the new quote is selected so the name appears in the field when you select new..  The user can keep this name or overwrite it.  Is this something I need to use an Auto Launch Flow for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're asking isn't possible using standard pages. We can't default fields based on another field value that is being selected within the screen.

Auto-launched flows won't help you in this situation as it would need something to call it, and until the record is saved we can't do that. The alternative would be to look to override the standard New action with a custom component, but that seems to be overkill in this situation. If you did this then you'd obviously also need to remove the Record Triggered Flow as this will override the value that user entered it.

Comment: Probably something to add too, I tried copying the value from a lookup in my org and that was actually possible even with the x.

Comment: OK thanks, looks like I won't bother continuing the search.  How were you able to copy the text I get a javascript:void(0); if I try anything